# Frogger-ish game

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, game

How about giving the good ol' arcade game Frogger a revival, Code Golf-style!

Your task is to create a version of this classic game, with as few characters of code as possible. Use the language of your choice (libraries, like *jQuery* etc., are allowed).

### Requirements

- You have 3 lives, and lose 1 life from:

  - moving outside the game scene.
  - getting hit by a vehice.
  - jumping in to water.
  - jumping to an already occupied home.
  - running out of time.
- The frog moves with arrow keys.
- There is a bug "teleporting" with set intervals between the five homes (the spaces between the grass at the top).
- You get *10* points when moving a step forward, *200* bonus points when catching a bug and *500* points when reaching an empty home.
- A timer ticks down, faster every level (the vehicles, frogs and logs should move faster as well each level).
- There should be 5 lanes of vehicles, and 3 lanes with logs and 2 with turtles.
- Each lane should move in a randomly chosen speed (within reasons).
- When an available home gets occupied, a frog appears at the starting point and you control that one from that point.
- When all five homes have been occupied, the timer restarts and the homes become empty. When the game ends, points from all levels are calculated and shown.

### Additional info

Start screen, music and highscore table is not needed. You also don't need to mimic the design to the pixel. Want it black and white? Want it really minimalistic? Or a cube instead of a frog or car? Works fine! Just keep the code tight. Shortest code wins!

[image]

Comment: Comments purged because they were obsolete. Please notify me of any lost information that may have been in deleted comments.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.3 - Ungolfed

I have not golfed this at all, as I was more interested in just getting a good-looking game working first. I am actually totally new to Tk, so if anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate them. The speeds now work properly. Let me know if you would like to see additional features, e.g. colors.

### Code

```
import tkinter as tk
import queue
import random    

class Lane():
 def __init__(self, row=-1, lanetype="none", direction=0, speed=0, width=0, maxnumber=0, replenish=0, length=0, gap=0):
  self.row = row
  self.type = lanetype
  self.direction = direction
  self.speed = speed
  self.width = width
  self.maxnumber = maxnumber
  self.replenish = replenish
  self.length = length
  self.gap = gap
  self.lanelastupdate = 0
  self.objects = []
  if(self.type == "car"):
   for index in range(self.width):
    if(len(self.objects) == self.maxnumber):
     break
    if((self.maxnumber - len(self.objects) == self.width - index) or random.random() < self.maxnumber/self.width):
     self.objects.append([index*self.direction + int((self.width-1)/2 - (self.width-1)*self.direction/2), self.row])
  if(self.type == "log" or self.type == "turtle"):
   if(self.direction == 1):
    start = 0
   else:
    start = self.width - 1
   lengthcounter = 0
   gapcounter = 0
   for index in range(self.width):
    if(lengthcounter < self.length):
     self.objects.append([start + index*self.direction, self.row])
     lengthcounter += 1
    else:
     gapcounter += 1
     if(gapcounter == self.gap):
      lengthcounter = 0
      gapcounter = 0
 ### end of __init__ ###
### end of Lane class ###

class Frogger():
 def __init__(self):
  # configure 'global' variables
  self.directions = ['Up', 'Down', 'Left', 'Right']
  self.width = 25
  self.height = 13
  self.frogstart = [12, 12]
  self.pointsforup = 10
  self.pointsforhome = 500
  self.pointsforbug = 200
  self.timerthreshold = 1000
  self.timerstart = 60
  self.speedchange = 2
  self.waterbordertop = 1
  self.waterborderbottom = 5
  self.minspeed = 10
  self.maxspeed = 15
  self.minbugspeed = 50
  self.maxbugspeed = 100
  self.timerspeed = 20    

  # configure program state variables
  self.q = queue.Queue(maxsize=1)
  self.updateticks = 0

  # configure game variables
  self.gameover = False
  self.speedup = 0
  self.timer = self.timerstart
  self.lives = 3
  self.score = 0
  self.frogposition = [0, 0]
  self.frogposition[0] = self.frogstart[0]
  self.frogposition[1] = self.frogstart[1]
  self.highest = 12
  self.movedup = False

  # configure the lanes of cars, logs, and turtles
  self.init_lanes()

  # configure the homes and the bug
  self.init_special()

  # configure TK window
  self.root = tk.Tk()
  self.label = tk.Label(text="Score: "+str(self.score)+" Lives: "+str(self.lives)+" Time: "+str(self.timer))
  self.label.pack()
  self.text = tk.Text(self.root, width=self.width, height=self.height, font=("Courier New", 14))
  self.text.bind("<Key>", self.key_event)
  self.text.focus_set()
  self.text.pack()

  # configure drawing sprites
  self.init_sprites()

  # run the game
  self.update_clock()
  self.process_world()
  self.root.mainloop()
 ### end of init ###

 def init_sprites(self):
  self.symbols = {"frog":chr(0x238), "rightcar":chr(187), "leftcar":chr(171), "turtle":chr(920), "log":chr(685), "bug":chr(1217), "grass":chr(993), "freehome":chr(164), "fullhome":"@", "road":"-", "water":chr(0x2248), "saferow":"*"}
  self.sprites = {value:key for key, value in self.symbols.items()}
  self.text.tag_configure("frog", foreground="chartreuse", background="dark green")
  self.text.tag_configure("rightcar", foreground="yellow", background="black")
  self.text.tag_configure("leftcar", foreground="yellow", background="black")
  self.text.tag_configure("turtle", foreground="orange red", background="cyan")
  self.text.tag_configure("log", foreground="sienna", background="cyan")
  self.text.tag_configure("bug", foreground="maroon", background="green")
  self.text.tag_configure("grass", foreground="orange", background="green")
  self.text.tag_configure("freehome", foreground="forest green", background="green")
  self.text.tag_configure("fullhome", foreground="red", background="green")
  self.text.tag_configure("road", foreground="gray", background="black")
  self.text.tag_configure("water", foreground="navy", background="cyan")
  self.text.tag_configure("saferow", foreground="pink", background="black")
 ### end of init_sprites ###

 def update_clock(self):
  self.timer -= 1
  self.label.configure(text="Score: "+str(self.score)+" Lives: "+str(self.lives)+" Time: "+str(self.timer))
  if(self.gameover == False):
   self.root.after(max(1, self.timerthreshold - self.speedup), self.update_clock)
 ### end of update_clock ###

 def key_event(self, event):
  direction = event.keysym
  if(direction in self.directions):
   try:
    self.q.put(direction, block=False)
   except:
    pass
 ### end of key_event ###

 def process_world(self):
  # acquire user input and process it if necessary
  if(self.q.qsize() > 0):
   self.move_frog(self.q.get())

  # update the state of non-frog objects
  self.update_world()

  # draw the world
  self.draw_world()

  # schedule another pass unless the game is over
  if(self.gameover == False):
   self.root.after(self.timerspeed, self.process_world)
  else:
   self.root.after(self.timerspeed, self.gameover_screen)
 ### end of process_world ###

 def move_frog(self, d):
  x = self.frogposition[0]
  y = self.frogposition[1]
  if(d == 'Up'):
   y -= 1
  elif(d == 'Down'):
   y += 1
  elif(d == 'Left'):
   x -= 1
  else:
   x += 1
  if(x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < self.width and y < self.height):
   self.frogposition[0] = x
   self.frogposition[1] = y
   self.movedup = False
   if(d == 'Up' and y < self.highest):
    self.movedup = True
 ### end of move_frog ###

 def gameover_screen(self):
  self.label2 = tk.Label(text="Game over! Your score was: " + str(self.score))
  self.label2.pack()
 ### end of gameover_screen ###

 def update_world(self):
  # update the internal timer
  self.updateticks += 1

  # check for loss conditions
  if((self.timer == 0) or self.hit_by_car() == True or self.in_water() == True or self.home_twice() == True or self.in_grass() == True):
   self.process_death()
   return

  # credit good moves up
  if(self.movedup == True):
   self.score += self.pointsforup
   self.highest = self.frogposition[1]
   self.movedup = False

  # check for win condition
  if(self.at_home() == True):
   self.process_victory()
   return

  # check for total win
  if(self.all_done() == True):
   self.process_win()
   return

  # update the positions of the cars, logs, and turtles
  self.update_positions()
 ### end of update_world ###

 def all_done(self):
  if(len([x for x in self.homes if x[1]==False])==0):
   return True
  return False
 ### end of all_done ###

 def process_win(self):
  self.gameover = True
  return
 ### end of process_win ###

 def process_death(self):
  self.lives -= 1
  if(self.lives < 1):
   self.gameover = True
   return
  self.frogposition[0] = self.frogstart[0]
  self.frogposition[1] = self.frogstart[1]
  self.highest = 12
  self.timer = self.timerstart
 ### end of process_death ###

 def hit_by_car(self):
  for lane in self.lanes:
   if(lane.type != "car"):
    continue
   for car in lane.objects:
    if(car == self.frogposition):
     return True
  return False
 ### end of hit_by_car

 def in_water(self):
  if(self.frogposition[1] < self.waterbordertop or self.frogposition[1] > self.waterborderbottom):
   return False
  for lane in self.lanes:
   if(lane.type == "turtle"):
    for turtle in lane.objects:
     if(turtle == self.frogposition):
      return False
   elif(lane.type == "log"):
    for log in lane.objects:
     if(log == self.frogposition):
      return False
  return True
 ### end of in_water

 def home_twice(self):
  for h in self.homes:
   if(h[0] == self.frogposition and h[1] == True):
    return True
  return False
 ### end of home_twice

 def in_grass(self):
  if(self.frogposition[1] == 0 and self.at_home() == False):
   return True
  return False
 ### end of in_grass

 def at_home(self):
  for h in self.homes:
   if(h[0] == self.frogposition):
    return True
  return False
 ### end of at_home ###

 def process_victory(self):
  self.score += self.pointsforhome
  if(self.bugposition == self.frogposition):
   self.score += self.pointsforbug
  for h in self.homes:
   if (h[0] == self.frogposition):
    h[1] = True
    break
  self.timer = self.timerstart
  self.frogposition[0] = self.frogstart[0]
  self.frogposition[1] = self.frogstart[1]
  self.highest = 12
  self.speedup += self.speedchange
 ### end of process_victory ###

 def init_lanes(self):
  random.seed()
  self.lanes = []
  self.lanes.append(Lane(row=11, lanetype="car", maxnumber=10, replenish=0.1, direction=1, width=self.width, speed=random.randint(self.minspeed, self.maxspeed)))
  self.lanes.append(Lane(row=10, lanetype="car", maxnumber=8, replenish=0.2, direction=-1, width=self.width, speed=random.randint(self.minspeed, self.maxspeed)))
  self.lanes.append(Lane(row=9, lanetype="car", maxnumber=5, replenish=0.6, direction=1, width=self.width, speed=random.randint(self.minspeed, self.maxspeed)))
  self.lanes.append(Lane(row=8, lanetype="car", maxnumber=9, replenish=0.4, direction=-1, width=self.width, speed=random.randint(self.minspeed, self.maxspeed)))
  self.lanes.append(Lane(row=7, lanetype="car", maxnumber=6, replenish=0.3, direction=1, width=self.width, speed=random.randint(self.minspeed, self.maxspeed)))
  self.lanes.append(Lane(row=5, lanetype="turtle", direction=-1, length=3, gap=4, width=self.width, speed=random.randint(self.minspeed, self.maxspeed)))
  self.lanes.append(Lane(row=4, lanetype="log", direction=1, length=3, gap=3, width=self.width, speed=random.randint(self.minspeed, self.maxspeed)))
  self.lanes.append(Lane(row=3, lanetype="log", direction=-1, length=8, gap=9, width=self.width, speed=random.randint(self.minspeed, self.maxspeed)))
  self.lanes.append(Lane(row=2, lanetype="turtle", direction=1, length=2, gap=6, width=self.width, speed=random.randint(self.minspeed, self.maxspeed)))
  self.lanes.append(Lane(row=1, lanetype="log", direction=-1, length=4, gap=4, width=self.width, speed=random.randint(self.minspeed, self.maxspeed)))
 ### end of init_lanes

 def init_special(self):
  self.bugposition = [2, 0]
  self.buglastupdate = 0
  self.bugspeed = random.randint(self.minbugspeed, self.maxbugspeed)
  self.homes = [[[2, 0], False], [[7, 0], False], [[12, 0], False], [[17, 0], False], [[22, 0], False]]
 ### end of init_special ###

 def update_positions(self):
  if(self.updateticks - self.buglastupdate >= self.bugspeed - self.speedup):
   self.buglastupdate = self.updateticks
   while(True):
    freeslots = [x for x in self.homes if x[1] == False]
    if(len(freeslots)==0):
     self.bugposition = [-1,-1]
     break
    if(len(freeslots)==1):
     self.bugposition = freeslots[0][0]
     break
    newhomeindex = random.randint(0, 4)
    if(self.homes[newhomeindex][0] != self.bugposition and self.homes[newhomeindex][1] == False):
     self.bugposition = self.homes[newhomeindex][0]
     break

  for lane in self.lanes:
   lanemovedfrog=False
   if(self.updateticks - lane.lanelastupdate >= lane.speed - self.speedup):
    lane.lanelastupdate = self.updateticks
   else:
    continue
   for o in lane.objects:
    if(o == self.frogposition and lanemovedfrog==False):
     self.move_frog(self.directions[int(0.5*lane.direction + 2.5)])
     lanemovedfrog=True
    o[0] += lane.direction
    if((o[0] < 0) or (o[0] >= self.width)):
     lane.objects.remove(o)
   if(lane.type == "car" and len(lane.objects) < lane.maxnumber and random.random() < lane.replenish):
    lane.objects.append([int((self.width-1)/2 - (self.width-1)*lane.direction/2), lane.row])
   if(lane.type == "log" or lane.type == "turtle"):
    if(lane.direction == 1):
     start = min([x[0] for x in lane.objects])
     nxt = min([x for x in range(start, self.width) if (len([y for y in lane.objects if y[0] == x]) == 0)])
     if(start >= lane.gap or (nxt - start) < lane.length):
      lane.objects.append([0, lane.row])
    else:
     start = max([x[0] for x in lane.objects])
     nxt = max([x for x in range(start, -1, -1) if (len([y for y in lane.objects if y[0] == x]) == 0)])
     if(self.width - start - 1 >= lane.gap or (start - nxt) < lane.length):
      lane.objects.append([self.width - 1, lane.row])
   lane.objects.sort()
 ### end of update_positions ###

 def draw_world(self):
  self.text.state = "normal"
  self.text.delete('1.0', str(self.width + 1) + '.' + '0')
  drawstr = ""
  # draw home row
  newstr = self.symbols["grass"] * self.width
  for h in self.homes:
   if(h[1] == False):
    if(self.bugposition == h[0]):
     newstr = self.str_replace(newstr, h[0][0], self.symbols["bug"])
    else:
     newstr = self.str_replace(newstr, h[0][0], self.symbols["freehome"])
   else:
    newstr = self.str_replace(newstr, h[0][0], self.symbols["fullhome"])
  drawstr += newstr
  drawstr += "\n"

  # draw water rows
  for index in range(self.waterborderbottom - self.waterbordertop + 1):
   newstr = self.symbols["water"] * self.width
   for lane in self.lanes:
    if(lane.row == index + self.waterbordertop):
     for o in lane.objects:
      if(lane.type == "log"):
       newstr = self.str_replace(newstr, o[0], self.symbols["log"])
      elif(lane.type == "turtle"):
       newstr = self.str_replace(newstr, o[0], self.symbols["turtle"])
   drawstr += newstr
   drawstr += "\n"

  # draw safe row
  drawstr += self.symbols["saferow"] * self.width
  drawstr += "\n"

  # draw car rows
  for index in range(len([l for l in self.lanes if l.type == "car"])):
   newstr = self.symbols["road"] * self.width
   for lane in self.lanes:
    if(lane.row == self.waterborderbottom + 2 +index):
     for o in lane.objects:
      if(lane.direction == 1):
       newstr = self.str_replace(newstr, o[0], self.symbols["rightcar"])
      elif(lane.direction == -1):
       newstr = self.str_replace(newstr, o[0], self.symbols["leftcar"])
   drawstr += newstr
   drawstr += "\n"

  # draw safe row
  drawstr += self.symbols["saferow"] * self.width

  # do actual drawing
  self.text.insert('1.0', drawstr)

  # draw frog
  self.text.delete(str(1 + self.frogposition[1]) + '.' + str(self.frogposition[0]))
  self.text.insert(str(1 + self.frogposition[1]) + '.' + str(self.frogposition[0]), self.symbols["frog"])

  # apply colors
  for sprite in self.sprites.keys():
   self.highlight_pattern(sprite, self.sprites[sprite])

  # turn off editability
  self.text.state = "disabled"
 ### end of draw_world ###

 def str_replace(self, targetstr, index, char):
  return targetstr[:index] + char + targetstr[index+1:]
 ### end of str_replace ###

 def highlight_pattern(self, sprite, tag):
  start = self.text.index("1.0")
  end = self.text.index("end")
  self.text.mark_set("matchStart", start)
  self.text.mark_set("matchEnd", start)
  self.text.mark_set("searchLimit", end)
  count = tk.IntVar()
  while True:
   index = self.text.search(sprite, "matchEnd", "searchLimit", count=count, regexp=False)
   if(index == ""):
    break
   self.text.mark_set("matchStart", index)
   self.text.mark_set("matchEnd", "%s+%sc" % (index, count.get()))
   self.text.tag_add(tag, "matchStart","matchEnd")
 ### end of highlight_pattern ###
### end of Frogger class ###

# Run the game!!!
frogger = Frogger()
```

Comment: I think the problem comes from updating the screen. If your program runs at 60fps, it takes around 16ms to do. This means your main-loop can't possibly run every 1ms. (This is the general logic, but I have no expertise with Tkinter or other GUI-systems)

Comment: Might be worth asking on SO about this. Please post a link here if you do.

Comment: I took your advice and asked on SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999478/python-tkinter-call-to-after-is-too-slow The screen refresh rate is set to every 20 update ticks, which should be every 20ms, or a rate of 50fps. This seems like it should be trivially easy for any modern computer.

Comment: Based on the SO answer, I have changed the program to use a 20-ms timer. I have also fixed a few other bugs in the meantime. If there is enough interest, I will look to add colors to make the ASCII easier to see. Feel free to comment with suggestions, I will do my best to implement them.

Comment: This works really well (make sure to run with `python3 filename` rather than `python filename`). I've awarded you the bounty as the other answer isn't yet finished

Comment: Thanks! I cleaned up the code a bit and added colors. The color highlighting function is directly from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781670/tkinter-text-highlighting-in-python

Comment: I added unicode characters for slightly better graphics, increased the font size, and fixed a number of small bugs. If anyone has further improvements to suggest, let me know! This was a lot of fun to write, and it's not even that bad to play ;)

Answer (score 1):

### C++ 1710

I started an ASCII console version. The frog can move. Still working on other requirements.
Haven't yet done object detection or scoring. Frog moves with keys w,a,s,d.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
#define P(x) cout<<x<<endl
#define R 13
#define C 25
string bank="=========================";
string water="~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";
string road="-------------------------";
string log="LOG";
string car="CAR";
string frog="FROG";
string leaf="LEAF";
string rows[R];
bool gameover=false;
int frogX,frogY;

void insertObject(string obj, int row, int pos)
{
    string tmp=rows[row].erase(pos,obj.size());
    tmp.insert(pos,obj);
    rows[row]=tmp;
}

void newBoard()
{
int r,r2;
for(int i=0;i<R;i++)
{
    r=rand()%2+1;//1-3
    if(i==0||i==6||i==12)
    {
        rows[i]=bank;
    }
    else if(i>0&&i<6)
    {
        rows[i]=water;
        for(int j=0;j<r;j++)
        {
            r2=rand()%21;
            insertObject(log, i, r2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        rows[i]=road;
        for(int j=0;j<r;j++)
        {
            r2=rand()%21;
            insertObject(car, i, r2);
        }
    }
}
insertObject(frog, 12, (int)(C-4)/2);
frogX=(int)(C-4)/2;
frogY=12;
insertObject(leaf, 0, (int)(C-4)/2);
}

void showBoard()
{
#ifdef WIN32
system("cls");
#else
system("clear");
#endif
for(int i=0;i<R;i++)
{
    P(rows[i]);
}
}

void playGame()
{
char c;
int i=0;
while(!gameover)
{
cin>>c;
switch(c)
{
case 'a':
    if(frogX!=0)frogX--;
    break;
case 'w':
    if(frogY!=0)frogY--;
    break;
case 'd':
    if(frogX<21)frogX++;
    break;
case 's':
    if(frogY!=12)frogY++;
    break;
default:
    break;
}
insertObject(frog, frogY, frogX);
showBoard();
i++;
if(i>12) gameover=true;
}
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    char play='y';
    while(play=='y')
    {
        newBoard();
        showBoard();
        playGame();
        P("Play Again (y/n)?");
        cin>>play;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define s string` for a bit more golfing (note: this appears to be one char shorter than `typedef string s;`)

Or you could do `#define t typedef`, then `t string s;`, although I don't know whether that works

Comment: also you might want to use `++i` instead of `i++`